# Web service Unmarshalling response error in WebSphere

Tags: websphere, jax-ws

I'm developing a web service client consumer.

The client classes are generated using cxf wsdltojava code generator.

When I run the client in tomcat, everything work ok, but when I deploy the client to
 WebSphere 7.0, I get the unmarshaller error as :

```
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.wrapper.impl.JAXBWrapperException: An internal assertion  
     error occurred. The com.mycompany.webservice.model.LoginResponse JAXB object does not have a LoginResponse xml property.
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.wrapper.impl.JAXBWrapperToolImpl.unWrap(JAXBWrapperToolImpl.java:83)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.demarshalResponse(DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.java:144)
... 16 more
```

The wsdl is like this :

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
...
<xsd:element name="LoginResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LoginResult" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ticketID" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

and the entity response class is :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"loginResult",
"ticketID"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "LoginResponse")
public class LoginResponse {

@XmlElement(name = "LoginResult")
protected boolean loginResult;
protected String ticketID;
```

and the service class is :

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", name = "AuthenticationSoap")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
public interface AuthenticationSoap {

@RequestWrapper(localName = "Login", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", className = "com.mycompany.webservice.model.Login")
@WebMethod(operationName = "Login", action = "http://tempuri.org/Login")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "LoginResponse", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", className = "com.mycompany.webservice.model.LoginResponse")
@WebResult(name = "LoginResponse", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
public LoginResponse login(
    @WebParam(mode = WebParam.Mode.IN, name = "username", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
    java.lang.String username,
    @WebParam(mode = WebParam.Mode.IN, name = "password", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
    java.lang.String password,
    @WebParam(mode = WebParam.Mode.INOUT, name = "ticketID", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
    javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.String> ticketID,
    @WebParam(mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT, name = "LoginResult", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
    javax.xml.ws.Holder<java.lang.Boolean> loginResult
);
}
```

Is there anybody who know what the problem here is in my definitions?

Sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that wsdl2java is not adding the attribute "endpointInterface" to your @WebService annotation. You will need to assure your WSDL contains a wsdl:portType.

IBM has a great article that explains the WSDL to Java mappings:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdoc400/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.iseries.doc/info/ae/ae/rwbs_map.html

Comment: Thanks for response, but the problem is not for that.

I have portType in my wsdl file. The web service is called and successful response is returned. But in unmarshaling response, I face the problem.

I trace it and found that in tomcat, the mule CxfMessageDispatcher class is using JaxWsClientProxy as proxy class, but in WebSphere, it usese JaxWsProxyHandler as proxy class.

I changed the class loading attribute of project to parent last, also disabled WebSphere Web Service by putting the flag "DisableIBMJAXWSEngine: true" in manifest file of project, but nothing changed.

Sincerely.

Comment: I understand. My reason for recommending that is I've seen others who have had this same issue and it was because the endpointInterface attribute on the webservice annotation was missing. Upon unmarshaling, it can't determine the type. For sanity sake, could you try to manually add the endpointInterface attribute to your webservice annotation?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to check whether your .wsdl has complexType or not as complexType name="LoginResponse". if not you may want to try to add complexType name="LoginResponse"...
Second thing i'd recommend is that you could switch your websphere running mode. if you run as development mode, unclick the box or if you're running it without development mode chech the box and try again. this is a defect i think. Once you may want to upgrade your websphere maybe with a fix pack.